# Rigid and soft body collision - no interaction

Tags: soft-body

I'm trying to animate a basketball through the net, but I can't get collision to work.
I tried flipping normals for the net, but no luck.
These are my settings - I tried the net WITH and WITHOUT the rigid body physics - still nothing.
Any ideas what I might be missing?

EDIT:
I am able to make it interact with passive rigid body that I keyframe through the net, but ACTIVE does not. I can't figure it out.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled 'Collision' on the ball? (the Collision in the Physics tab, not the Collision settings of the Rigid Body physics)

Comment: Just tried adding the collision - didn't change anything, still passes through :(

Comment: Did you re-bake the cloth? Also, you seem to have the cloth collision collection set to 'basket' - is the ball also in that collection?

Comment: Yes, same collection. Hmm I didn't do any baking yet.

Comment: That is what I'm going for, but I still have no idea why his net reacts to the ball, while mine does not when the ball is an active rigid body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of 2.8: https://developer.blender.org/T60079
You need to switch back to 2.79 if you want to feature

You can fake the gravity simulation and do as explained here:

- the net should be *cloth*
- the ball should be set as *collision*

[image]

Comment: Read the edit - try a free falling ball

Comment: Ah I just realized you wrote it's a bug.
Thank you!